# Mixture distribution fitting containing a uniform distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions, histograms

I have a dataset that is clearly the mixture of 3 known distributions which can be generated as follows:

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2130, 80], 9000];
data2 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{2250, 4050}], 6000];
data3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[4100, 90], 3000];
```

which when overlapping the histograms with my real data, "mydata" reveals:

```
Histogram[{mydata, data1, data2, data3}, {"Raw", 2000}, 
PlotRange -> {{1500, 4500}, {0, 250}}]
```

[image: Overlap Histograms]

where the light yellow histogram is my real data. To drive the point that my dataset is a mixture distribution of a two normal and a uniform distribution even further, here is histogram comparison of the distributions mixed compared to my real data:

```
Histogram[{mydata, Flatten[{data1, data2, data3}]}, {"Raw", 2000}, 
PlotRange -> {{1500, 4500}, {0, 250}}]
```

[image: mixture]

However, when I go to fit my real data with a mixture distribution with initialized parameters of the generated data, my uniform distribution is being bullied out:

```
params = FindDistributionParameters[mydata, 
MixtureDistribution[{g, h, i}, {NormalDistribution[a, b], 
UniformDistribution[{c, d}], 
NormalDistribution[e, f]}], {{g, .5}, {h, .3}, {i, .2}, {a, 
2130}, {b, 80}, {c, 2250}, {d, 4050}, {e, 4100}, {f, 90}}]
```

the results are

```
{g -> 0.494885, h -> 0.000655526, i -> 0.504459, a -> 2143.23, 
b -> 79.4785, c -> 2250., d -> 8414.1, e -> 3491.59, f -> 659.049}
```

where the weight of the uniform distribution, *h*, is being reduced to nothing.
This is the resulting fit:

```
p1 = Histogram[mydata, {"Raw", 2000}, PDF, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 6000}, {0, .003}}];

p2 = Plot[
PDF[MixtureDistribution[{g, h, i}, {NormalDistribution[a, b], 
UniformDistribution[{c, d}], NormalDistribution[e, f]}]][x] /. 
params, {x, 0, 5000}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6000}, {0, .003}}]
```

[image: Mixture Distribution PDF fit]

My end game is to obtain an analytical function for the mixture PDF, but I'll face that hurdle when I get there. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I also added

```
ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", 
Method -> {"NMaximize", PrecisionGoal -> 1000, 
AccuracyGoal -> 1000, MaxIterations -> 10000}
```

as an argument in the FindDistributionParameters to no avail.

Edit: Here is a [pastbin](https://pastebin.com/bd3yUank) of "mydata".

Comment: Not sure what's going on because if I replace `mydata` with `mydata = Join[data1, data2, data3]`, then the weights work out fine.  Can your data be made available?

Comment: Please post your data on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) if it is too large to include in your question.

Comment: Hmmm that's strange, I'll follow up tomorrow when I have the data on hand.

Comment: I've edited my post with a pastebin link of "mydata". Thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: Here's why you got the results you did:  `mydata` has a `MinMax` of `{0.9, 8414.1}` and the combination of `data1`, `data2`, and `data3` has a `MinMax` of `{1767, 4391}` (at least with one random realization).  The point is that the 50 or so points that are way outside of the simulated data are causing the results you see.  Take those 50 points away and all of the parameters are about what you expect.  How to fix that?  That will be in my next comment - after lunch.

Comment: Ah, I see. I can definitely get away with cleaning my original data set. Thanks again JimB, you are my hero.

Comment: An alternative is to include `WorkingPrecision -> 30` but while that will have more reasonable results than not removing those 50 data points if you can justify removing those 50 extreme points, that produces a "nicer" result.  (I'm usually very, very conservative about tossing any data.)

Comment: If you only need a smooth version of the distribution and don't have to export the pdf outside of *Mathematica*, then the following can use all of the data and get an appropriate display:  `skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
Plot[PDF[skd, x], {x, 0, 8500}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: I came back to talk about the smoothness actually. Instead of using the uniform distribution in the middle, which is inherently discontinuous, I used a generalized gaussian, implemented as the ExponentialPowerDistribution in Mathematica, which approximates a uniform under certain parameter conditions with fantastic results. Thanks so much for always giving quality feedback.